# PODS: limit result of relationsship field

Tags: wordpress, relationship, podscms

I have 2 Pods "Tools" with Field name and test and "Test" with Field date and tool. In the tool content type is test a relationsip field for field tool in Test.

When we want to get some relation field we do

```
$pod = pods( 'pod_name', get_the_id() );
$related = $pod->field( 'relationship_field' );
```

and I get list of results array 1, 2, 3 ... but I need only 2 results. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

```
$related = array_splice( $related, 0, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need the last 2 results (i have a tool with 4 tests and i need test 3 and 4, a other tool with 6 tests i need test 5 and 6). How can I do that?

Comment: Easy, $related = array_splice( $related, 2 )

Comment: Ah ok, but better, $related = array_splice( $related, -2 );
and i get the last 2 results. but I want to turn the output: first the last value and then the penultimate value. How?